# CSS transition buggy and stuttering in Safari but works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, web, safari, webkit

This is my first post here so sorry if something isn't formatted correctly.
CSS:

```
.para {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: transform 0.45s cubic-bezier(.2,.49,.32,.99) 0s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.45s cubic-bezier(.2,.49,.32,.99) 0s;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const para_el = document.querySelectorAll(".para");
let xVal = 0, yVal = 0;

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    xVal = e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2;
    yVal = e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2;

    para_el.forEach(el => {
        let speedx = el.dataset.speedx;
        let speedy = el.dataset.speedy;
        el.style.transform = `translateX(calc(-50% + ${-xVal * speedx}px)) translateY(calc(-50% + ${yVal * speedy}px))`;
    })
})
```

The above code is for a parallax effect. it works perfectly on Chrome but not on Safari. It works fine on both browsers up until I add the transition CSS but after that Safari refuses to correctly render it. It glitches and stutters about, almost as if Safari thinks the cursor is somewhere else for a fraction of a second, before snapping everything back to where it should be. I've spent over 2 hours trouble shooting this and I haven't got anywhere with it, I don't think it's a webkit issue since as far as I know Chrome uses webkit too on MacOS (since `-webkit-transition: 0s;` disables the transition on both browsers). Is this a Safari bug or does Safari just for whatever reason treat my CSS different to every other browser? Thanks.